# How do I authenticate and publish an npm package to artifactory from a build system such as bamboo?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, artifactory, bamboo

The `npm publish` instructions for artifactory (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry) state that you need to generate a credentials file and put this in the ~/.nmprc file. How does this work when the publishing is part of a CI pipeline? Do you execute this on the build agent, and then delete the file after the publish? Or is there a different method of authenticating available?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a access token is generated and used by your CI. You should never commit any config files with access tokens in it (Github also warns you within minutes if you do so). 
Here's a link to the artifactory help page where they setup jenkins with a access token: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-use-access-tokens-in-your-ci-environment/

Comment: I definitely wasn't suggesting committing credentials to git! Far from it. Your answer doesn't address the npm specifics.